# Loop a series of lists and put them into a dictionary

Tags: python

The values I'm getting are as follows:

```
[1, 'en', 'Apple']
[1, 'es', 'Manzana']
[2, 'en', 'Car']
[2, 'de', 'Auto']
[3, 'en', 'Palace']
```

The format I want to format is as follows.

```
{
  "words_list": 
    [
        {
            "word_id": 1,
            "word": {
                "en": "Apple",
                "es": "Manzana"
            }
        },
        {
            "word_id": 2,
            "word": {
                "en": "Car",
                "de": "Auto"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So how can I convert the given lists into a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another ideal job for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
import itertools

entries = [
    [1, 'en', 'Apple'],
    [1, 'es', 'Manzana'],
    [2, 'en', 'Car'],
    [2, 'de', 'Auto'],
    [3, 'en', 'Palace']
]

word_list = [
    {
        'word_id': word_id,
        'word': {
            entry[1]: entry[2]
            for entry in group
        }
    }
    for word_id, group in itertools.groupby(entries, key=lambda x: x[0])
]
```

```py
>>> word_list
[{'word_id': 1, 'word': {'en': 'Apple', 'es': 'Manzana'}},
 {'word_id': 2, 'word': {'en': 'Car', 'de': 'Auto'}},
 {'word_id': 3, 'word': {'en': 'Palace'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [[1, 'en', 'Apple'],
[1, 'es', 'Manzana'],
[1, 'hh', 'hfhjfj'],
[2, 'en', 'Car'],
[2, 'de', 'Auto'],
[3, 'en', 'Palace']]

res = defaultdict(list)

for x in data:
    res[x[0]].append(x[1:])

d = {'words_list': [{'word_id': x, 'word': dict(res[x])} for x in res]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Please check it

```
words_list = []

def add(arr):
    id = arr[0]
    lang = arr[1]
    meaning = arr[2]

    added = False
    # check if `id` exist in array
    for word in words_list:
        if word.get("word_id") == id:
            added = True
            word["word"][lang] = meaning

    # if `id` doen't exist in array, add id to array
    if added == False:
        words_list.append(
            {
                "word_id":id,
                "word": {
                    lang:meaning
                }
            }
        )

add([1, 'en', 'Apple'])
add([1, 'es', 'Manzana'])
add([2, 'en', 'Car'])
add([2, 'de', 'Auto'])
add([3, 'en', 'Palace'])

print(words_list)
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but what if the parameters are given in tuples, not lists?